# How to limit a phrase search to official announcements?

Tags: google-search

How can I search a saying, or a quote (I mean, real quote) in Google? For example, I want to search for any statement from The Supreme Court that has this keyword: `the fact that`. Is it possible?

Comment: Which Supreme Court?

Comment: any court in the world? I mean, if I don't specify which country, does it matter?

Comment: If that's what you want to search against, that's fine. I don't know how useful that would be, though. Presumably you'd only see that phrase in documents from Supreme Courts (named as such) in English-using countries.

Comment: I don't mind about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for exact phrases, enclose them in quotes. For instance, this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=united+states+supreme+court+%22the+fact+that%22) seems to have returned some pretty good results:

```
united states supreme court "the fact that"
```

If you want to limit this to "official" pronouncements, you need to limit the site(s) searched using the `site:` operator.

So, to search that phrase on the official site for the U.S. Supreme Court, you'd [use](https://www.google.com/search?q="the+fact+that"+site%3Awww.supremecourt.gov):

```
"the fact that" site:www.supremecourt.gov
```

You'll find *a ton* of useful information here: [How to search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?ref_topic=3081620&vid=1-635806919192754697-3587097224)

Comment: I know that to find the exact phrase, enclose them in the quotation marks. What I mean is that only search in the official announcement of the court, not a random criticize to the court article which contains `the fact that`

Comment: You can limit the site that's searched, so if you have the site where the announcements are posted, use the `site:` operator.

Comment: What you're really asking, then, is how to limit searches to "official" pronouncements.

Comment: Hmm, good work around. I think this is the answer.